# I couldn't get message sender name from socket.io (Reactjs with Socket.io)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

Please help me when i want to show message sender name near message, my data came undefined, message is sending successfuly but socket.nickname get undefined. How can i fix this problem. Can u help me ? I've been working on this for a very long time. I just couldn't realize where I was wrong. Finally I decided to seek help.

Server.js

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

const users = {};


http.listen(8005, () =>{
   console.log('8005 portu dinleniyor...');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('yeni-kullanici', function (data, callback) {
      if (data in users){
          callback(false);
      } else {
          callback(true);
          socket.nickname = data;
          users[socket.nickname] = socket;
          updateUsers();
      }
   });

    function updateUsers(){
        io.sockets.emit('users', Object.keys(users));
    }

    updateUsers();

    socket.on('mesaj-gonder', function (data) {
        io.sockets.emit('mesaj', {msg: data, nick: socket.nickname});
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', (data) => {
        if (!socket.nickname) return;
        delete users[socket.nickname];
        updateUsers();
    });
});
```

client

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import io from "socket.io-client";

class Home extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            url:'http://127.0.0.1:8005'
        }
    }

    kullaniciAl(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const userName = $('#userName').val();
        const socket = io(this.state.url);
            socket.emit('yeni-kullanici', userName, function (data) {
                if (data){
                    $('.giris').hide();
                    $('.chat').show();
                }else{
                    $('.uyari').show();
                    $('#userName').val('');
                }
            });
    }

    yeniMesaj(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const mesaj = $('#mesaj').val();
        const socket = io(this.state.url);
        socket.emit('mesaj-gonder', mesaj);
        $('#mesaj').val('');
    }

    render() {

        const socket = io(this.state.url);
        socket.on('users', function (data) {
            let html = '';
            for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                html += data[i] + '<br/>';
            }
            $('#users').html(html);
        });

        socket.on('mesaj', function (data){
            $('#contentMesaj').append('<b>' + data.nick + ': </b>' + data.msg + '<br/>');
        });
        return (
           <div>
               <div className="giris">
                   <div className="alert alert-danger uyari" role="alert" style={{display: "none"}}>
                       Bu kullanıcı adı zaten mevcut. Tekrar Deneyiniz...
                   </div>
                   <form>
                       <div className="form-group">
                           <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Kullanıcı Adı</label>
                           <input  className="form-control" id="userName" placeholder="Kullanıcı adınızı girin..."/>
                       </div>
                       <button onClick={this.kullaniciAl.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary">Gönder</button>
                   </form>
               </div>
               <div className="row chat" style={{display: "none"}}>
                   <div className="col-md-8" >
                       <div id="contentMesaj" style={{height: "500px",border:"1px solid"}}>

                       </div>
                       <div className="message">
                           <form>
                               <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                   <input id="mesaj" className="form-control" placeholder="Mesajınızı Yazın..." aria-describedby="basic-addon2"/>
                                   <div className="input-group-append">
                                       <button onClick={this.yeniMesaj.bind(this)} className="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Gönder</button>
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                           </form>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div className="col-md-4">
                       <div className="head col-md-12">
                           <h3>Kullanıcılar</h3>
                       </div>
                       <div className="kul col-md-12">
                           <span id="users"/>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
        );
    }
}


export default Home;
```

Result SS :

[Result SS :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvN4H.png)

Comment: Hi, try to move the socket out of the render method, you should declare it on componentdidmount function.